# yumdownloader doesn't resolve dependency?

Tags: centos7, yum

According to [man yumdownloader](https://linux.die.net/man/1/yumdownloader):

```
   --resolve
          When downloading RPMs, resolve dependencies and also download the required packages.
```

However, when I tried:

```
$ sudo yumdownloader devtoolset-7-gcc-c++.x86_64 --destdir /opt/downloaded_rpms/ --resolve
```

It didn't download the dependency:

```
$ ll /opt/downloaded_rpms/
total 11644
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11683460 Dec 25 17:10 devtoolset-7-gcc-c++-7.2.1-1.el7.sc1.x86_64.rpm
```

And so when I attempted to install, it complained:

```
# sudo yum install /tmp/devtoolset-7-gcc-c++-7.2.1-1.el7.sc1.x86_64.rpm 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Examining /tmp/devtoolset-7-gcc-c++-7.2.1-1.el7.sc1.x86_64.rpm: devtoolset-7-gcc-c++-7.2.1-1.el7.sc1.x86_64
Marking /tmp/devtoolset-7-gcc-c++-7.2.1-1.el7.sc1.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package devtoolset-7-gcc-c++.x86_64 0:7.2.1-1.el7.sc1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: devtoolset-7-gcc = 7.2.1-1.el7.sc1 for package: devtoolset-7-gcc-c++-7.2.1-1.el7.sc1.x86_64
...
...
--> Processing Dependency: devtoolset-7-libstdc++-devel = 7.2.1-1.el7.sc1 for package: devtoolset-7-gcc-c++-7.2.1-1.el7.sc1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: devtoolset-7-runtime for package: devtoolset-7-gcc-c++-7.2.1-1.el7.sc1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: devtoolset-7-gcc-c++-7.2.1-1.el7.sc1.x86_64 (/devtoolset-7-gcc-c++-7.2.1-1.el7.sc1.x86_64)
           Requires: devtoolset-7-gcc = 7.2.1-1.el7.sc1
Error: Package: devtoolset-7-gcc-c++-7.2.1-1.el7.sc1.x86_64 (/devtoolset-7-gcc-c++-7.2.1-1.el7.sc1.x86_64)
           Requires: devtoolset-7-libstdc++-devel = 7.2.1-1.el7.sc1
Error: Package: devtoolset-7-gcc-c++-7.2.1-1.el7.sc1.x86_64 (/devtoolset-7-gcc-c++-7.2.1-1.el7.sc1.x86_64)
           Requires: devtoolset-7-runtime
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Did I do something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

According Red Hat [Bug 1152326](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1152326):

> ... this is the expected behavior when the dependencies are already installed. `yumdownloader --resolve` will only download the missing dependencies. You can use an empty `installroot` to download the package along with all its dependencies:
>
> ```
> # yumdownloader NAME --resolve --installroot=/path/to/installroot --releasever=/
> ```

Comment: This is backwards